# Why the getRGB() method is written the way it did? Is there an alternative way to write getRGB() method?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, synchronized

I'm new to Java. I saw the code below from Java tutorial Oracle. I'm struggling to understand the purpose of this code snippet:

```
    public synchronized int getRGB() {
        return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
    }
```

I understand how bitwise operator works but I'm struggling to understand why the getRGB() method is written the way it did. Is there an alternative way to write getRGB() method?

```
public class SynchronizedRGB {

    // Values must be between 0 and 255.
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;
    private String name;

    private void check(int red,
            int green,
            int blue) {
        if (red < 0 || red > 255
                || green < 0 || green > 255
                || blue < 0 || blue > 255) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public SynchronizedRGB(int red,
            int green,
            int blue,
            String name) {
        check(red, green, blue);
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void set(int red,
            int green,
            int blue,
            String name) {
        check(red, green, blue);
        synchronized (this) {
            this.red = red;
            this.green = green;
            this.blue = blue;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public synchronized int getRGB() {
        return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
    }

    public synchronized String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public synchronized void invert() {
        red = 255 - red;
        green = 255 - green;
        blue = 255 - blue;
        name = "Inverse of " + name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchronizedRGB color = new SynchronizedRGB(0, 0, 0, "Pitch black");
        System.out.println(color.getRGB());
    }
}
```

Comment: 8 bits is all you need to represent 0 through 255. I suspect it was written this way to prevent excessive use of memory(each colour using a full 32 bit int when they only need 8) and/or clock cycles(three function calls vs one). You can certainly override the method if you wish.

Comment: It's a packed `int`, this is typically how RGB(A) values are represented in most graphics circles. You could write it to return an `int` array, but what does each element actually mean?  You could make a `RGB` class which just contains getters for each value, but it's not as transportable as a packed `int` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component is a byte (8 bits), an integer is 32 bits, so you can store 4 8 bit numbers in a 32 bit integer, 8 bits for alpha, red, green and blue. The >> or << operators are bit shift operators, moving the bits in a number by the specified amount. 1 << 1 results in 2. Looking at the binary sequence...
00000001 << 1 = 00000010

Answer (score 2):

The left shift operator `<< x` is equivalent to multiplying by 2^x, so you can write it as

```
return ((red * 65536 ) + (green *256) + blue);
```

Comment: You meant 256 surely?